# How to cancel a task's continuation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

My class has a method which produces a `Task<int>` object using a `TaskCompletionSource<int>`. Then it does some asynchronous operations and sets the result. I need to know whether I can trust the task's `ContinueWith` method or not:

```
public Task<int> CalculateAsync()
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource();
    DoSomeAsyncStuffAndSetResultOf(source);

    source.Task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Is this reliable?"));
    return source.Task;
}
```

Can the caller of `CalculateAsync` method do something with the produced task and prevent its continuation from running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `CancellationToken` into various overloads of [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx)... that would be the most idiomatic way of just cancelling the continuation, IMO.

I don't think there's anything you can do to the *parent* task to cancel continuations. I kinda hope not, anyway...

EDIT: Okay, it sounds like you're trying *not* to let that happen. No, you don't need to worry. Unless the caller can somehow make the task run forever without ever completing, being cancelled or faulting, the continuation will run.

Comment: Oh, I see - no, the continuation will always run (assuming the caller can't force the task to simply run forever, never completing).

Comment: Deleted the comment after I saw your edit. What if he calls Dispose before I set the result of the task?

Comment: @ŞafakGür: As per the docs for Task.Dispose, that will throw an InvalidOperationException.